# whats causing these stains on the leaves of my eggplant

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables

recently these dark brown stains started to appear on the new growth of my eggplants leaves and I'd like to find out what's causing it. I started it from seed on early may and moved it to a 10 gallon/40something liter pot in June.

Although I didn't damage the root ball it took a long time to recover from repotting, it started to wilt when placed even in the early morning sun. When it finally started to recover I moved it to where it sits now in my roof deck. It's quite hot where I'm from so I've set a 99% mesh above it to protect from the midday sun, it gets about 6 hours of direct sunlight outside of the central hours of the day.

From what I've googled these stains don't look like the most common fungal diseases so I wonder if they could be caused by a virus or something else. There is no serious pest attacking the plant, just a few white flies and Cicadellidae and other eggplants I've got in a raised bed unprotected from the midday sun don't have these stains. Any idea of what's happening to it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I forgot to include pics and now when I try to edit the post and paste images from imgur I get an error. I'll try again later, sorry.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's anything "wrong" with that plant. This appears to be the fairly common across many different plants "new leaves showing their native color until more chlorophyll develops and they turn green" behavior.

*e.g.* peonies come up quite red, then turn green. This is a milder example of the same behavior from what I see in these pictures.

Comment: Excellent catch. Not unusual to see a color foreshadowing of flower or fruit showing up in leaf or stem.